# Understanding potential difference between two points that are not separated by a resistor in a wire

Tags: electricity, potential

Question: When considering two electrons in a closed circuit that are not separated by a resistance, why is there no potential difference between them if one of the electrons is farther from the positive terminal than the other, meaning that it should have more electric potential energy?

My understanding is that electric potential energy at a point is dependent on the distance from the charge that is creating the electric field. In this case, as the distance from the positive terminal increases, the electrons have more potential to do work, and thus they have more electric potential energy .Why is this reasoning flawed?

Answer (score 2):

In a real circuit, unless it’s superconducting, there will always be resistance between points even if that value is low.  I think you are conflating the potential in an electric field with the electric potential in a conductor.  In a super conducting element, all points are the same potential. In a real circuit with conductivity, there is a small voltage drop with current flow (for typically appropriate wiring) but for the most part it is all at the same potential.  So if current flows through a copper wire, your potential (voltage) is highest at one end and it drops gradually off along the length of the wire.  A real example is if you add an extension cord to a typical lightbulb, it will be slightly dimmer than if you do not use it.